# Strip empty objects on generated json/jsonb on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I stip all the nulls using `json_strip_nulls` easily but it causes to have some empty objects on the results:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "organization_id": 1,
  "pairing_id": 1,
  "location": {},
  "device": {
    "tracking_id": 1
  },
  "events": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Is there any simple way to remove the empty objects too? In here **location** and the empty object in **events** are have to be removed.
You can find the complete examples with test data [here in DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uPKcqZZpeWRLdXZ8abNq8r/1).

Comment: I don't think there's a function for this, but you can replace `{}` and `[]` by `null` and then strip nulls again

Comment: I don't know how to apply that solution either.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8964a04e1a7c31b864311ce3567bd595

Comment: Perfect. It's definitely good enough to be an answer to this question!

Answer (score 1):

In your certain example I'd suggest to add a couple of helper functions:

```
create or replace function json_object_nullif(
    _data json
)
returns json
as $$
    select nullif(json_strip_nulls(_data)::text, '{}')::json
$$ language sql;

create or replace function json_array_nullif(
    _data json
)
returns json
as $$
    select nullif(_data::text, '[null]')::json
$$ language sql;
```

and then adjust your view, so instead of `json_build_object(...)` you can use `json_object_nullif(json_build_object(...))` and the same for `json_agg`.

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8964a04e1a7c31b864311ce3567bd595)